# RewriteCond Query String .htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite

EDIT: I must add something.First of all i want to change url display because of SEO.If i use www for reach my website there is no problem, second link is appears and everything is ok.

But if i remove "www" from link, it changing to first url and i doesn't want that.

I want to change

[http://www.mysite.com/index.php?*route*=epson-claria-uyumlu-yazici-kartus-dolum-murekkebi-500g.html](http://www.mysite.com/index.php?_route_=epson-claria-uyumlu-yazici-kartus-dolum-murekkebi-500g.html)

to

http://www.mysite.com/epson-claria-uyumlu-yazici-kartus-dolum-murekkebi-500g.html

how I can do it?

I tried

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_route_=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

but it is not working.

My .htaccess is

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]

RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=common/home$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.mysite.com? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

If you have to visually change the address bar, leave the RewriteRule in place as I described above, and put this in your `index.php` before any output:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['route']))
{
    header('Location: '.urlencode($_REQUEST['route']));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you beat me to fixing that typo ;)

Comment: Internal Server Error has been occured when i added it. :/

Comment: @codeGenius have you checked the edited code? I erroneously typed `}` instead of `]`.

Comment: @BenM Yep, i didn't see that at my first try.Now i tried edited code but it doesn't change the url and page content returning 404 not found.

Comment: It won't visually change the URL. How are you trying to access the page (i.e. what have you typed in the location bar)?

Comment: You're rewriting everything at the end of your .htaccess file with `RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]`. Replace that with the line in my answer...

Comment: @BenM OMG, i want to visually change it, is it possible with .htaccess?

Comment: @BenM Thank you for your support but maybe i must search solution with another way.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. The above will work perfectly for what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: @BenM i'm explained with details on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850907/remove-index-phproute-from-opencart

Comment: @BenM: The problem is the URL the user sees.  He wants to redirect to the shorter URL, but will also probably need to rewrite the shorter URL to actually go to the longer one.

Answer (score 1):

**Initial note:** I'm not an Apache guru so don't rely blindly on my answer.

I would first redirect to `www.` if required

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Then make it go to the page indicated by the `_route_` query variable

```
# if it is the index page...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index\..+)?$ [NC]
# and if the query string starts with _route_=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_route_=(.*)$
# redirect
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Server variable `SERVER_NAME` in last line might need to be changed with `HTTP_HOST`.

Comment: As far as the redirect-to-`www.`, i actually prefer redirecting everything to the non-`www.` domain.  The `www.` version just stays around cause a bunch of people got trained that "web site addresses start with 'www'".  But i'd like to lead people away from that nonsense.  (Not that it's that big a deal here anyway; whether you redirect `www` or not, or to which domain, is immaterial to the actual question.)