# Remove index.php?route= from OpenCart

Tags: .htaccess, seo, opencart

I'm a .NET developer but my friend called me for support.I made some changes with .htaccess but i'm corrupted SEO.

Everything started with "www" tag on url.I see we get some errors when we are not using "www" and i'm changed .htaccess.I'm added rewrite rule and redirected mysite.com to www.mysite.com.Our problems are solved but now we have another problem.

We are using Opencart - SEO and it's enabled.Our products seems like

```
http://www.mysite.com/epson-claria-uyumlu-yazici-kartus-dolum-murekkebi-500g.html
```

when we are reaching with www.

But if i remove "www" tag on url, it seems like

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?_route_=epson-claria-uyumlu-yazici-kartus-dolum-murekkebi-500g.html
```

and it corrupt SEO.

I want to see second url like first one.

I'm tried play with seo_url.php , .htaccess but it doesn't change anyting.

I'm also tried solution on [Remove index.php?route=common/home from OpenCart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813809/remove-index-phproute-common-home-from-opencart) but it's not worked for me.

Now my seo_url.php is default, i get back my changes.And my .htaccess is

```
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=common/home$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.mysite.com? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_route_=$1 [L]
```

Please help me before i get crazy.I spend 3 hours for that.

Thank you for all,
Greetings

Comment: This does what you need - http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=7197

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This Its working for me using .htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /index\.php\?_route_=?([^&\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
```

Comment: 1+ The one and only working and user-friendly solution.

Answer (score 1):

Also have the same problem and any that I found not solved my problem. But! I remember that I also working with Laravel and in this engine well working url path. Don't ask why I associated OpenCart with Laravel. So I enable SEO radio button in *System -> Settings -> Server* you also can disable it I don't see difference in the site work.

This solution consist from several part:

**1.** In your root folder replace *.htaccess* file content with next shapshot:

```js
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**2.** Go to */system/library/url.php* and find `link` method and replace it with next:

```js
public function link($route, $args = '', $secure = false) {
  if ($this->ssl && $secure) {
    $url = $this->ssl . 'index.php?route=' . $route;
  } else {
    $url = $this->url . 'index.php?route=' . $route;
  }

  if ($args) {
    if (is_array($args)) {
      $url .= '&amp;' . http_build_query($args);
    } else {
      $url .= str_replace('&', '&amp;', '&' . ltrim($args, '&'));
    }
  }

  foreach ($this->rewrite as $rewrite) {
    $url = $rewrite->rewrite($url);
  }

  $url = str_replace('index.php?route=', '', $url);

  return $url; 
}
```

Since you changed *.htaccess* in root folder and change url generating method you also need remember about admin part. If you what see pretty url in admin just **copy .htaccess from root folder to /admin folder**.

If you want save orignal url in admin side you must little bit change `link` method with next:

```js
public function link($route, $args = '', $secure = false) {
  if ($this->ssl && $secure) {
    $url = $this->ssl . 'index.php?route=' . $route;
  } else {
    $url = $this->url . 'index.php?route=' . $route;
  }

  if ($args) {
    if (is_array($args)) {
      $url .= '&amp;' . http_build_query($args);
    } else {
      $url .= str_replace('&', '&amp;', '&' . ltrim($args, '&'));
    }
  }

  foreach ($this->rewrite as $rewrite) {
    $url = $rewrite->rewrite($url);
  }

  //  Skip admin path
  if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/admin') !== 0) {
    $url = str_replace('index.php?route=', '', $url);
  }

  return $url; 
}
```

**Result:**

*Before*

`http://YOUR_SITE/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=52`

*After*

`http://YOUR_SITE/product/product&product_id=52`

*Before*

`http://YOUR_SITE/index.php?route=account/login`

*After*

`http://YOUR_SITE/account/login`

Answer (score 0):

Just try this..

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: I agree with you @Natasha. If you look at the .htaccess file, the url it redirects to seems to be wrong. See this line: `RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]`. The part I have an issue with is **__route__**, why are there underscores? When I took those away in my .htaccess file the rewrite worked.

Comment: I know this is a bump but it's important for anyone else that comes across this - removing the underscores breaks it. It seems like it works but it breaks SEO-friendly URLs for products. So stupid that OpenCart uses two different methods of routing when it could easily use one. Or better yet, follow CodeIgniter's Controller method. People rave about how good OpenCart is but the minute you want to do anything different with it, it falls over. I'm giving up on it. It's a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Old question i know but maybe someone would find it helpful: The reason SEO urls break if you change the HTACCESS rule is that they depend on `_route_` for clarification that "yes this is a request for a clean url, no its not a standard route".

If you change `index.php?_route_=` in the HTACCESS you must also change the `_route_` IF conditionals in `/catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php`. It may get heavily wonked out though if you do this, try it on test stores first.

Nothing should be seeing the `_route_` except you in the logs or things like analytics logs since its a masked utility uri. If you see real humans are asking what the link is, then take action. Otherwise, its best to leave it.

Comment: how we can ?? can you paste here what change will be occur in seo_url.php? and it will be helpful for opencart version 2.2.0.0??